# is there a c# qualification I can go for?

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there was any qualifications for c# , kind of like the Zend Qualification for PHP that would be recognised by an employer?

Comment: all the microsoft certifications seem so broad, is there one that is more specifically for c# that you would reccommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no certification specifically for C#.

Because Microsoft designed and developed C# to be part of the .Net framework, which encompasses multiple languages, Microsoft certifications are not language specific.

When you take a certification exam, you do have the option to choose C# or VB as the language the exam will use when asking programming questions.

- If you are a Windows forms developer - Choose the Windows Developer 3.5 MCPD certification track.
- If you are a web application developer - Choose the ASP.NET Developer 3.5 MCPD certification track.
- If you are both a Windows forms and web application developer - Choose the Enterprise Application Developer 3.5 MCPD certification track.

Comment: what about if i want to be a desktop application developer?

Comment: A Windows forms developer is a desktop application developer. 
Since a Windows forms project is the most common type of desktop application project that’s what I call it.

Comment: o ok brilliant. it looks like that is the one i would go for then. thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Consider Microsoft's Certifications.

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-overview.aspx

Comment: With only 4 seconds apart, and links to the exact same page, I must say you're both worth my upvotes... :P

Comment: all the microsoft certifications seem so broad, is there one that is more specifically for c# that you would reccommend?

Comment: Yes, I recommend you to start with Exam 70-315 if you are in web development or Exam 70-316 if you are in windows forms development

Comment: Oh and to be MCSD, you will have to pass those as well: Exam 70-320, Exam 70-300, Exam 70-229. Details here: http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/mcsd.aspx

Comment: o ok thanks for the advice, it all seems very tricky is there one page, that it shows you almost a tree diagram of the exams and the ones you have to take/can take in regards to getting the mcpd cert? also do you know any site that has prices for training etc?

Comment: I would suggest this path: 70-316, 70-320, 70-300, 70-229. And you will be MCSD. Juste my tought about all of this: avoid jobs where employers take Microsoft's Certifications seriously. And you will solve two problems: having to pass those certification, and having to get a bad job ;)

Comment: so you reccommend not actually taking the certification exams and just learn it from tutorials etc?

Comment: There is lot of things where it's more interesting to put your money and time in. For exemple be involved in developer's communities like StackOverflow is something you should do. Having a high reputation will certainly helps. Since I decided to put some of my time in this community two weeks ago, I learnt a lot !

Comment: Education is certainly one thing Ryan, experience and the ability to solve problems in advance and as they come to you immediately are another. You can do the latter without the former, and you can do the former without the latter. The age old saying "don't put all of your eggs in one basket" springs to mind, but then I'm formally "uneducated" and yet I'm quite capable of solving almost every problem that comes my way.. and remember, in many jobs you are not an individual, you are a team.

Answer (score 4):

I'd take a look at the Microsoft certifications for something you'd be interested in.

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-overview.aspx

Comment: With only 4 seconds apart, and links to the exact same page, I must say you're both worth my upvotes... :P

Comment: all the microsoft certifications seem so broad, is there one that is more specifically for c# that you would reccommend?

Comment: Take a look at the Microsoft Certified Professional Developer (MCPD) program.  This has 3 tracks, Windows Developer 3.5, ASP.NET Developer 3.5 or Enterprise Application Developer 3.5.  Ideally you'll want to have a couple of years of Microsoft development experience first.

Comment: it all seems very tricky is there one page, that it shows you almost a tree diagram of the exams and the ones you have to take/can take in regards to getting the mcpd cert? also do you know any site that has prices for training etc?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of them, for example see [Microsoft Certified Solution Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/mcsd.aspx#tab2) program.

Comment: all the microsoft certifications seem so broad, is there one that is more specifically for c# that you would reccommend?

Answer (score 0):

This is the highest grade you can get as developer

MCPD
http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/mcpd.aspx#tab2

You are can only make some of the needed certs too.
With all passed exams you get your MCPD, each single succeeded exam is an MCTS - XYZ title.

edit:
You can choose the language, but nothing in the exams are really language specific.
You learn about .NET Framework in general.

Comment: sorry i didnt really understand this, can you explain more please?

Comment: The language in the exams is chooseable by yourself, you can take VB.NET or C# as far as i known.
The questions are not language specific: means that you dont gettin asked for special VB.NET/C# things.

I this answer doesn't fit, pls explain what you dont understand and i try to write more understandable eng ;)

Comment: it all seems very tricky is there one page, that it shows you almost a tree diagram of the exams and the ones you have to take/can take in regards to getting the mcpd cert? also do you know any site that has prices for training etc? btw the eng is very good this time

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Overview (done by a friend) for the .NET MCPD 2.0
http://www.hartsoft.net/MCP_MCAD_MCPD.pdf

If you want do to it for .NET 3.5 you have to pass the 70-356 exam, these are the
basics. 
For the other exams (Winform, Web, distributed etc) you have to replace the numbers in the pdf with the numbers from http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/mcpd.aspx#tab2.

I dont know if i can put a name of a training company here, cause it's a little advertisement.
(I add the name if iam allowed to).

Take a look at google or something else for books ("MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit" for example).